# Assemble code for ppc64

Tags: c, assembly, 64-bit, cpu-registers, powerpc

I have an assemble code for 32bit ppc and i confused as how to convert it for 64bit. Can some show the links on the ABI's for 64bit ppc.

Here is a sample function , how would the 64bit version of it look like ?

```
SLEAF(cpu_save_context)

stw    r0,   0(ARG0)
stw    sp,   4(ARG0)    /* Stack frame pointer */

stw     r2,   8(ARG0)
stw     r3,  12(ARG0)
stw     r4,  16(ARG0)
stw     r5,  20(ARG0)
stw     r6,  24(ARG0)
stw     r7,  28(ARG0)
stw     r8,  32(ARG0)
stw     r9,  36(ARG0)
stw  r10,  40(ARG0)
stw  r11,  44(ARG0)
stw     r12,  48(ARG0)

stw    r13,  52(ARG0)    /* Small data area pointer */

stw    r14,  56(ARG0)   /* C-registers */
stw    r15,  60(ARG0)
stw    r16,  64(ARG0)
stw    r17,  68(ARG0)
stw    r18,  72(ARG0)
stw    r19,  76(ARG0)
stw    r20,  80(ARG0)
stw    r21,  84(ARG0)
stw    r22,  88(ARG0)
stw    r23,  92(ARG0)
stw    r24,  96(ARG0)
stw    r25, 100(ARG0)
stw    r26, 104(ARG0)
stw    r27, 108(ARG0)
stw    r28, 112(ARG0)
stw    r29, 116(ARG0)
stw    r30, 120(ARG0)
stw    r31, 124(ARG0)

mfcr    r0        /* Fetch condition register */
stw    r0,  128(ARG0)

mflr    r0        /* Fetch link register */
stw    r0,  132(ARG0)

mfctr    r0        /* Fetch count register */
stw    r0,  136(ARG0)

mfxer    r0,        /* Fetch fixed-point exception Register */
stw    r0,  140(ARG0)

li    ARG0,    1    /* Return TRUE to caller. */
blr

END(cpu_save_context
```

Comment: http://pds.twi.tudelft.nl/vakken/in101/labcourse/instruction-set/?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stw (store word) on the general purpose registers (r0, sp, r2-r31) and the special purpose registers LR, CTR, XER, you should use std (store doubleword). And you need to change ARG0's hardcoded offsets to store 8 bytes, so the offsets would be "0, 8, 16, 24,..." instead of "0, 4, 8, 12, ...". You might also need to consider whether there is space allocated at the ARG0 pointer for the additional storage required for doublewords instead of words.

For example:

```
std    r0,   0(ARG0)
std    sp,   8(ARG0)    /* Stack frame pointer (offset was previously 4) */
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of material regarding the new ppc64 ABI, aka, ABI v2.

The most important one is Official ELFv2 ABI Specification. There are also some presentation about it. All of them are found on the following URL.

https://wiki.debian.org/ppc64el#ABI_Documentation